# How to get the element's id by Angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have several articles regarding this but don't get the proper solution for my problem. I am using Angular js 1.5 and Bootstrap 3.

My code is like,

```
<a href="" class="noUnderline" data-trigger="focus" data-toggle="popover"  data-placement="bottom" data-content = "{{helpSrv.helpMessage}}" > 
 <i class="fa fa-info-circle infoCirc" ng-click="helpSrv.showPopOverInfo($event)" id="forecastAttainmentId"> </i>
</a>
```

I want to show the Popover when the `i`icon will be clicked. Now, `helpSrv` is a service that is written in Angular JS. `helpMessage` is chosen by the `id` of the element. `helpSrv` is a service that contains two things like,

```
var s = this
s.helpInfo = {
"forecastAttainmentId": "Some text"
}
s.showPopOverInfo = function (event) {      
        var helpSelect = event.target.id
        s.helpMessage = s.helpInfo[helpSelect]
        console.log(s.helpMessage)
}
```

Now when I click the `i` icon for the first time it shows `{{helpSrv.helpMessage}}` in the popover. Next time it shows the actual message i.e. `Some text`. I think the delay is caused due to the function call. How to solve that?? Or is there any way to get the `id` of the element automatically using angular (without any plugin) so that I can use `data-content="{{helpSrv.helpInfo['id of the element']}}"` to get the message for the Popover.

Comment: is it really `ng-lick`? you mispelled it, it should be `ng-click`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to access the `i` tag by using `$("#forecastAttainmentId").click(function(){...}`. Also you need to initialize `helpSrv.helpMessage` to be able to see the data when the popover loads for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

It's about [AngularJs digest cycle](https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/). Try using $timeout:

```
s.showPopOverInfo = function (event) {     
    $timeout(function(){ 
        var helpSelect = event.target.id; // Always end lines with a semicolon
        s.helpMessage = s.helpInfo[helpSelect];
        console.log(s.helpMessage);
    }, 0);
};
```

Comment: I have used $timeout. But still it doesn't help

Comment: Please create an example on jsfiddle or jsbin etc.